# Does luxury vinyl flooring need to be installed all the way under a gas stove?

Tags: vinyl-flooring

I want to install luxury vinyl floor in my kitchen. If I don't want to move my gas stove, can I install it up to first couple of inches under front side of stove? Is that OK with a floating floor (tongue and groove)? Can it be left like this?

Answer (score 2):

This is actually done quite often, especially with gas appliances. People don't want to disconnect the gas lines to move their stoves. Many times the gas company will disconnect/reconnect for you.

I have never floored around an appliance but I see it a lot. If you choose to do this, do yourself a favor and save a few lengths of the flooring in case you decide later to correct this.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t skimp often as some places have ended up without a stove and the buyer backed out until we finished the space on 1 flip and the next one we finished it after a renter damaged the stove, it can be done but after a couple of issues I totally finish dishwasher, stove and closet spaces , things my mentor said to skip but is 20$ worth the loss of a sale later ??? Your choice, yes it can be done but I quit doing this in the early 90’s.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t foresee this causing any issues, and if it did then you could just move the stove at that time and rectify the situation. Probably a non issue